Clarification on function properties: injective and surjective
I want to see if I am on the right path for if we have a $f: \mathscr P( \Bbb N) \to \Bbb N \cup \{ \infty \}$ be the function which assigns to each subset $A \subseteq \Bbb N$ the cardinality of that subset, i.e., $f(A) = \vert A \vert$.
Can we say f is surjective?

Yes!
For $n \in \Bbb N$ , there exists at least one subset $A$ of $\Bbb N$ such that $\vert A \vert = n$. For $n = \infty$, there exists at least one subset of $\Bbb N$ that contains infinite elements

Can we say f is injective?

Also yes.
Different subsets have different cardinalities, so $f$ maps different subsets to different elements in the codomain

What are the elements of $f^{−1}(n)$ for a given $n \in \Bbb N$ ?
$f^{-1}(n)$, which represents the pre-image of $n$ under function $f$, consists of all subsets of $\Bbb N$ that have the same cardinality $n$

For injectivity, are you really sure that $f({1,2,3,4})\ne f({54,74,90,2010})$?

For surjective, it's probably a good idea to actually give an example of such a set that has cardinality $n$ (resp. $\infty$). This is easy to do for any particular $n$ like if $n=3$ you can take $A = {4,18,2006}$, but how would you describe a set for a general $n$?

Your answer re injectivity has to be wrong.  Cantor's Theorem tells us that for any set $A$, it's never possible to injectively map $\mathscr P(A)$ into $A$.  (This is the famous "diagonalization" proof.)  See the comment of @HagenvonEitzen to see where you went wrong.
